# How to Get global contacts from EWS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exchangewebservices

I'm working on `microsoft EWS Webservice` i found the solutions for fectching current users data . Now i need to fetch `global contacts from EWS`. is there any help?thanks in Advance.

currently im using below string for getting user data

```
                <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\
                xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"\
                xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\
                xmlns:t=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types\">\
                <soap:Body>\
                <ResolveNames xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages\"\
                xmlns:t=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types\"\
                ReturnFullContactData=\"true\">\
                <UnresolvedEntry>smtp:%@@atea.dk</UnresolvedEntry>\
                </ResolveNames>\
                </soap:Body>\
                </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Search for contacts in the Global Address List you just need to set the SearchScope to ActiveDirectory see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565329(v=exchg.150).aspx

eg

```
<soap:Header>
<t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" /> 
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<m:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="true" SearchScope="ActiveDirectory">
<m:UnresolvedEntry>smtp</m:UnresolvedEntry> 
</m:ResolveNames>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The thing to keep in mind with this method is that it will only return a max of 100 entries. If you have a really large directory and have Exchange 2013 then use findpeople http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191039(v=exchg.150).aspx instead

Cheers
Glen